# groovy/grails - domain object and tooltips

Tags: grails, groovy

Given a grails domain object with properties like

```
Integer displayOrder
Boolean visible
```

... what would be the best way to associate meta information about these fields for display on tooltips in edit view?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What sort of meta information?

Comment: ... short description about the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just add a message to message.properties with the content:

```
// messages.properties
myDomain.myField.tooltip = Enter an awesome field value for this field
```

And then render it appropriately in the markup alongside the field, or wherever:

```
<g:message code="myDomain.myField.tooltip"/>
```

Comment: FYI, there's a nice Grails tooltip plugin that you can use for your views.